# Using Designated Initializers with the Heap

Tags: c, heap-memory, designated-initializer

One can use `designated initializers` as shown below (for "billy") without issue, but when the same initialization approach is used on dynamic memory things will break at compile-time.

What are the restrictions for using designated initializers?

Aside from *where* (i.e. the address) to which we are writing, what makes these two initializations different? Why can we not use designated initializers with dynamic memory?

```
struct student{
    char *name; 
    int age;
};


void print_student(struct student* st){
    printf("Student: %s is %d years old\n", st->name, st->age);
}


int main(void) {    
    srand(time(NULL));
    struct student *molly_ptr = malloc(sizeof(struct student));

    struct student billy = {
                            .name = "billy",
                            .age = rand()%30
                           };

    *molly_ptr = {
                    .name = "molly",
                    .age = 25
                 };

    //molly_ptr->name = "molly";
    //molly_ptr->age = 25;

    print_student(&billy);
    print_student(molly_ptr);


    return 0;
}
```

---

```
error: expected expression before '{' token
  *molly_ptr = {
               ^
```

Comment: Initialization and assignment are two different things. The second thing you're trying to do is an assignment. That syntax isn't available for those AFAIK. (Unrelated to heap/stack.)

Comment: `char *name` should preferably be declared as `const char *name`.

Comment: @Lundin, the code was generated only for this question. There is also technically a memory leak.

Comment: @Lundin: Technically, not in reality, though. Every resource is released right before `main` exits, also your operating system comes with a memory management system, it'll free all memory after your process exits anyway. Git, for example, doesn't free any resources at all.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use a compound literal:

```
*molly_ptr = ( struct student ){ .name = "molly", .age = 25 };
```

This is almost identical to:

```
struct student temp = { .name = "molly", .age = 25 };
*molly_ptr = temp;
```

Comment: Very interesting, although [this](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Compound-Literals.html) source suggests the data being pointed to is now on the stack. This would cause a memory leak given the code above. I was not aware of this syntax.

Comment: @sherrellbc Incorrect. molly_ptr is still pointing to allocated memory. The entire struct is copied to that memory. That is made abundantly clear in my second example.

Comment: This is something that is very interesting to me and I don't know which one of you is right. If this was C++ code, I could see it being copied, but as this is C, I think that the pointer is just pointing to something on the stack.  Is there something that could clarify this? It would probably make a good question on its own.

Comment: @callyalater, We dereference the pointer to a `struct student` object, and the assignment does a deep copy of the struct to memory. From what I can make of the documentation, the compound literal creates an unnamed object (either automatic or static duration depending on its contents and modifiers) and the compiler generates the deep copy instructions. Read the final two paragraphs of [this](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Compound-Literals.html) documentation for gotchas in C++.

Comment: @callyalater The pointer is pointing to the address returned my `malloc`, that means heap memory...

Comment: Looking at the assembly from the previous comments makes sense that it is doing a deep copy. But is that gcc specific or a c standard requirement?

Comment: @2501, I originally missed the dereferencing. It seems, then, that the cost of using this syntax with dynamic memory causes the structure to be initialized and then copied to the allocated memory block, approximately doubling the time/instruction cost. An effect worth considering.

Comment: @sherrellbc *approximately doubling the time/instruction cost.* What are you basing you conclusion on?

Comment: @2501, The GNU documentation states that use of compound literals will either be static or automatic in storage duration. It further states that the unnamed structure created will be copied to the memory location (in this case *molly_ptr). So, assuming the case where the structure is not static, we first must allocate space on the stack, initialize the structure `struct student temp = { .name = "molly", .age = 25 };`, then copy the contents `*molly_ptr = temp;`. Relative to directly assigning the memory as `molly_ptr->name = "molly" .. etc` the use of CL would require more instructions.

Comment: @sherrellbc C is an abstraction. Cpu's run assembly, not C. You will have to take a look at assembly, any other comparison is meaningless.

Comment: @2501, So it seems are you right -- at least for [this](https://goo.gl/2wohgJ) example. Perhaps the documentation was just being verbose regarding equivalent code. It states `In C, a compound literal designates an unnamed object with static or automatic storage duration`, but the allocated memory is being assigned directly in the generated assembly. So, in this case, there is no unnamed object of any storage duration.

Comment: @sherrellbc: It's interesting to see how, in your linked asm, the compound literal assignment and the assignment on it's own creates the same assembly.

Answer (score 4):

You have to write:

```
*molly_ptr = (struct student){
                                .name = "molly",
                                .age = 25
                             };
```